# memoryWarning in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, memory, warnings

I have an application with lots of view, about 20, accessible from two main menus, in each view there are labels, textfields and buttons, over a background image.
As data i've a global class and some array filled by xml files.

If memoryWarning fires, I should release what is not necessary, but if you are in one view, all in the other view is already deallocated right? What should I deallocate? Removing the global class i will lose essential data, the same for array.
Suggestions? (Sorry for bad english).

Comment: When switching to another view release the previous view. There is not enough information about your problem. How do you create your views?

Answer (score 1):

The views you have left are not necesserily deallocated, it all depends on the code. So you possible hold everything in the memory at the same time and memory is a scarse resource on iOS. So if you have a lot of views deallocate those that you don't currently use.

After receiving memory warning you should remove *everything* that you not need. Keep an eye on those XML files in arrays, XML files tend to be big: as the source and as a DOM tree in the memory after being parsed. You can try to make them all being lazy loaded and parsed, throw them away if not more needed, reload if needed again (you have then to save their loading state, nut this could be a simple array of boolean value instead of whole XML data).